# using meteor with coffeescript and jade: callback[i].call is not a function

Tags: node.js, meteor, coffeescript, pug

I have been trying out Meteor with Coffeescript and Jade. And for the most basic app I wrote the following code.

main.coffee

```
import './hello.coffee'

import './main.jade'
```

main.jade

```
head
    title Chatter

body
    h1 Welcome to Chatter!
    +hello
```

hello.coffee

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating'
import { ReactiveVar } from 'meteor/reactive-var'

import './hello.jade'

Template.hello.onCreated
    helloOnCreated: ->
        @counter = new ReactiveVar 0
        return

Template.hello.helpers
    counter: -> Template.instance().counter.get()

Template.hello.events
    'click button': (event, instance) ->
        instance.counter.set instance.counter.get() + 1
        return
```

hello.jade

```
template(name="hello")
    button Click me!
    p You have pressed the button #{counter} times.
```

Now when I am trying to run this app I am getting this error `Uncaught TypeError: callbacks[i].call is not a function`. I am rather new to this, so any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're currently passing `Template.hello.onCreated` an object with a `helloOnCreated` property. Just pass `Template.hello.onCreated` a function directly.

```
Template.hello.onCreated ->
    @counter = new ReactiveVar 0
    return
```

From [Meteor's documentation](https://docs.meteor.com/v1.3.5/api/templates.html#Template-onRendered), the `onCreated`, `onRendered` and `onDestroyed` properties accept functions.

The `events` and `helpers` properties accept objects, just like you have.

Comment: Ain't no thang! 

If you're trying out Meteor for the first time, I would suggest doing so with Meteor's built-in Blaze template engine and standard Javascript. I understand you can use Jade and Coffeescript, but you might get a better feel of Meteor's mechanics (and have more access to example code) by starting with their standard. Just a suggestion. Ignore at your leisure. :)

Comment: Yes I have followed the official todos tutorial with Blaze. I was making an app by myself so I thought of trying out CoffeeScript. Thank you for your suggestion and help. :)